# Autodesk Forge, Translator using wrong rootFile

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, solidworks, autodesk-model-derivative

### Summary

When I upload a zip file containing multiple SolidWorks assemblies and parts, an assembly contains the same name as my rootFile, and my rootFile is sorted later in a alphabetic order. The translator is using the wrong rootFile for the translation.

Could this be a bug in the translation service?

### Example

```
   example.zip
   ├── part1.sldprt
   ├── part2.sldprt
   ├── an assy.sldasm    <-- This file will be selected by translator
   └── assy.sldasm       <-- This file is selected as rootFile
```

Let's say I upload the zip file above, `"example.zip"`, and then request a translation with `"assy.sldasm"` as rootFile.

After completion, when I request the manifest of the translated file, the "rootFile"`is now "an assy.sldasm"`.

### Conclusion

My conclusion is that the translator matches filenames without requiring a match on the full filename.
This means, that because `assy.sldasm` is sorted after `an assy.sldasm` it will match to `an assy.sldasm` first.

Files to replicate the issue can be sent upon request.

Comment: Although I have not dataset of Solidworks, I can reproduce this problem with linked files of Inventor, AutoCAD or Revit. it looks translation job finds the file which contains the string rootFileName, and returns the first one (in sorted) ,instead of matching exact the string of rootFileName. Sorry for the problem. I logged it with our engineer team. The internal ticket is: DERI-5444.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. We have worked around it temporarily by renaming the assembly’s affected. Thanks for adding an entry, hope it gets resolved soon.

Comment: I posted the comment as answer for more searchable by others. I'd appreciate if you could vote/accept it, though it is about an issue of Forge API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting the comment as an answer for more searchable by others:
*Although I have not dataset of Solidworks, I can reproduce this problem with linked files of Inventor, AutoCAD or Revit. it looks translation job finds the file which contains the string rootFileName, and returns the first one (in sorted) ,instead of matching exact the string of rootFileName. Sorry for the problem. I logged it with our engineer team: DERI-5444*

Comment: Hi @KarlEK, Sorry this ticket is still open which means our engineer team has not yet resources to handle, which depends on the priority of the request. I am checking with team if they could share any update on that.